# Laravel Vue js : How can I update a component form Javascript like this:

Tags: laravel, vue.js

in my blade.php use one component

```
<loading :prop_show_loading="show_loading"></loading>
```

Still in my blade.php

This Doesn't work

```
<script>
    var show_loading = true;
</script>
```

---

this Does't work too

```
<script>
    window.event = new Vue();
    window.event.$emit('prop_show_loading', 'true');
</script>
```

and my component doing this (window is not defined)

```
created(){
            let App = this;
            console.log(global.event);
            window.event.$on('close-modal', (event) => {
                this.prop_show_loading = true;
            })
        },
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

if you need pass the prop_show_loading value from laravel to loading vue component.

you don't use ":" in the head:

```
<loading prop_show_loading="show_loading"></loading>
```

and in the loading component use:

```
    export default {
        props: ['prop_show_loading'],
        ...
```

and than you can use `this.prop_show_loading` to get the value.